# dynamic linker error with rand() function

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, dynamic-linking

I already asked a question about this before but with reference to the following code again

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <dlfcn.h>

int rand() throw() {

    // get the original rand() function
    static auto original_rand = (decltype(&rand)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "rand");

    cout << "Call made to rand()" << endl;
    return original_rand();
}
```

Why does compiling this result in the following error

```
error: exception specification in declaration does not match previous declaration
```

Why would this happen? How does the linker know that this is just another rand() function I have declared myself but rather an existing version of `rand()`?

Comment: The linker hasn't the slightest clue, but you're not getting that far. That message is from the compiler saying that your `rand` doesn't look like another `rand` it knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your header files (`<iostream>` in my case) silently includes `<stdlib.h>`, which contains the [`rand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) function. The latter does not have any exception specification. In your code you try to overload `rand()`, but the signature is the same as the one from `<stdlib.h>` except the exception specifier (which is not part of the function type, so cannot overload on it alone), hence you get a **compile-time error** (not a linker error, as you mentioned in the question).

If you wonder why the function `rand()` silently included is also visible in the global namespace (not visible only as `std::rand` as you may expect), that's because often the C library functions are imported into the standard C++ header files via a direct

```
// <new_cpp_header>
#include <old_c_header.h>
```

followed by

```
namespace std
{
    using old_function_from_old_c_header;
}
```

so the function ends up in both global namespace as well as in `namespace std;`. This is not a very good practice IMO, but that's how most compilers do it nowadays.

For example, the `<cstdio>` file has:

```
// <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
namespace std
{
    using printf;
    // ...
}
```

so both `printf` and `std::printf` are visible, even though you include only `<cstdio>` (and not `<stdio.h>`).